# Connecting numpy array of points to form a contour?

Tags: python, opencv

```
def cnts_convex_hull(cnts,image):
    results=[]
    points=[]
    for cnt in cnts:
        for point in cnt:
            reg_point=point[0]
            print(reg_point)
            points.append(reg_point)
    results=np.array(points)
    # i want to add a fn to form a contour , then use convexhull() on it.

img=cv2.imread("3.jpg")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
min = np.array([0, 100 , 100])
max = np.array([179, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, min, max)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
##################################################
gray_res = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernal = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
gray_res = cv2.morphologyEx(gray_res, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernal)
##################################################
edges = cv2.Canny(gray_res, 100, 100)
cnts,h  = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]
cnts_convex_hull(cnts,img)
cv2.imshow('frame',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

the problem on my hand is simple, i have (after filtering and edge detecting and the usual stuff) something that looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUrYZ.png , which i want to eventually close to shape rather than 2 lines, so i want to form a convex hull on them and by them i mean the whole list of points for the 2 contours.
so in the above code i was able to get the points in a np.array()
but i cannot transform them in the shape of contour so i can preform convexhull on them

Comment: The easiest might be to find the ends of both lines/contours and draw lines between them on a copy of the image. Now you use findcontours to find the shape as a single contour.

Comment: that's actually a pretty neat idea!